# Why did the Pandavas suffer so much in spite of having Lord Krishna besides them?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas

They were on the path dharma and had to suffer so much whereas kamsa lived so lavishly for life?

Answer (score 1):

How much suffering or happiness one will get is decided by the Karma. Happiness is the result of good karma. Sufferings are the result of bad karma.

The main question is why someone suffer if the God is with them. God cannot take away sufferings and give happiness to you because that would be against the Law of Karma. Even Gods cannot escape the results of the Karma. This is the reason why you will find that even the avatars have sorrows and happiness.

God gives us good direction in our life. It helps those who fights against the evils (just like Krishna helped Pandavas).

God generally helps indirectly. God will help you if you are ready to help yourself. Just like how Krishna helped Arjuna to fight. For example, if you worship Ganesh, you will get good intellect so that you will be able to face all the challenges in the life. Worshiping the God in real sense is to follow his/her teachings or qualities. If you do that sincerely, you will get those qualities (that the God possesses), not magically, but because you are working towards achieving such qualities.

सुखस्य दुःखस्य न कोऽपि दाता परो ददाति इति कुबुध्दिरेषा ।
अहं करोमीति वृथाभिमानः स्वकर्मसूत्रग्रथितो हि लोकः ॥

सुख और दुःख देनेवाला कोई नहीं है । दूसरा आदमी हम को वह देता है यह विचार भी गलत है । "मैं करता हूँ" एसा अभिमान व्यर्थ है । सभी लोग अपने अपने पूर्व कर्मों के सूत्र से बंधे हुए हैं । (निषादराज गृहक कैकेयी और मंथराको दोष देता है तब लक्षमण की उक्ति)

Comment: So what were the past karmas of pandavas so they had to suffer so much?@Kaushik

Comment: कर्मणो ह्यपि बोद्धव्यं बोद्धव्यं च विकर्मण: |
अकर्मणश्च बोद्धव्यं गहना कर्मणो गति: || 4/17|| (from Gita)

It is not possible to point out exactly what was the past Karma for which one is getting happiness or sorrows.